# How can I search through an array to find an array that contains a certain value?

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I'm sure this is incredibly simple, but I'm new to arrays and I'm using the TMDB API and PHP. I'm trying to get the name of the director.
This is a shortened version of the array:

```
Array
(
    [credits] => Array
    (
            [crew] => Array
            (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 40243
                        [name] => Gil Junger
                        [department] => Directing
                        [job] => Director
                        [profile_path] => 
                    )
            )

    )
)
```

I've got this far:

```
$film_query = file_get_contents("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/".$film_id."?api_key=".$key."&append_to_response=credits,images&json_callback=?");
$film_json = json_decode($film_query, true);
$director = $film_json['credits']['crew']['job'];
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
function getDirector(array $crew) {
    foreach($crew as $person) {
        if($person['job'] == 'Director') {
            return $person['name'];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In your code, you would pass `$film_json['credits']['crew']` as the `$crew` parameter.